# Can the legacy pack be uninstalled?

Tags: 2013-sp1, configuration

Recently we had an issue with the system asking for the legacy pack... an upgrade was done without it and there were some "old-school" templates in the database. So I was thinking on maybe identifying all of them, remove them from the system, and then uninstall the legacy pack. Would that be possible? How about then removing the old "Template Types" from Tridion.ContentManager.config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've removed the legacy templates, I believe that if you re-run the installer with `LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE`, as per the [installation documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04), then you should be able to de-select the legacy pack and remove it from the system. That will probably also take care of removing the Template Types from your config.

Just be absolutely sure you've removed **all** of your legacy templates, including any old "default" ones lurking around, otherwise you could end up re-installing it again later.

If you have a Core Service client handy, point this code at the lowest publications in your BluePrint to output your templates with their template types:

```cs
var publicationId = "tcm:0-97-1";
var publication = (PublicationData)client.Read(publicationId, null);
var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
{
    Recursive = true,
    ItemTypes = new[]
    {
        ItemType.ComponentTemplate, ItemType.PageTemplate, ItemType.TemplateBuildingBlock
    }
};
var identifiableObjects = client.GetList(publication.RootFolder.IdRef, filter);
foreach (var identifiableObject in identifiableObjects)
{
    var template = (TemplateData)client.Read(identifiableObject.Id, null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", template.Id, template.TemplateType);
}
```

Comment: That's my plan, but wanted to check with you guys :)